# How can settings be reused across several builds in a TeamCity build chain?

Tags: teamcity, build-chain

There's a TeamCity build chain consisting of several builds such that some of them need to run in parallel:

- Build 1 runs
- Then builds 2.1 and 2.2 run in parallel
- Then build 3 runs
- Then builds 4.1 and 4.2 run

this is quite easy to setup. It so happens that 2.1 uses the same configuration parameters as 4.1 and 2.2 uses the same parameters as 4.2 so it's be good to somehow specify those once such that if 2.1 parameters are changed then 4.1 parameters are also changed consistently.

I don't see a place where configuration parameters can be set other than at build level. Can they be set elsewhere and reused across several builds of a build chain?

Comment: You can use templates: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/build-configuration-template.html

Comment: @Peska I tried it and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Create the configuration parameter in parent project of these, then you can use the same parameter in all child build configuration.

If any parameter change, it will affect to all other child build configuration.